# String operation in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

```
SELECT PARTITION_DATE||'|'||RECORD_ID||'|'||BILLING_ACCOUNT_NUM||'|'||BILLING_AC COUNT_SYSTEM||'|'||BILL_SERIAL_NUM||'|'||BILL_VERSION_NUM||'|'||SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ NUM||'|'||SERVICE_ACCOUNT_SYSTEM||'|'||PRIMARY_ASSET_ID||'|'||ASSET_ID||'|'||CHA RGE_CATEGORY||'|'||CHARGE_GROUP||'|'||CHARGE_TYPE||'|'||CHARGE_DATE||'|'||CHARGE _END_DATE||'|'||CHARGE_TIME||'|'||ORIGINATING_NUM||'|'||CHARGECARD_NUM||'|'||DIA LLED_NUM||'|'||COUNTRY_CODE||'|'||MOBILE_PROVIDER_CODE||'|'||DURATION||'|'||TM_C ALL_QUANTITY||'|'||DATA_UPLOAD||'|'||DATA_DOWNLOAD||'|'||CONTENT_DESCRIPTION||'| '||COST||'|'||COST_BEFORE_DISCOUNT||'|'||DISCOUNT||'|'||ROAMING_IND||'|'||VAT_IN D||'|'||VAT_RATE||'|'||CHARGE_CODE||'|'||SOURCE_SYSTEM||'|'||DESTINATION||'|'||F ILE_KEY||'|'||CREATED_DT||'|'||UPDATED_DT||'|'||CALLING_NUMBER||'|'||EVENT_DIREC TION||'|'||EVENT_TYPE||'|'||EVENT_ROAMING_COUNTRY||'|'||DISCOUNT_INDICATOR||'|'| |ACCT_CODE||'|'||AUTH_CODE||'|'||ACCESS_CHARGE||'|'||SERVICE_CHARGE||'|'||IMEI_N UMBER||'|'||EFB_FLAG||'|'||RATING_DISCOUNT_NAME||'|'||SUMM_USAGE_FLAG_BKP||'|'|| SUMM_USAGE_FLAG||'|'||PRE_BUNDLE_COST||'|'||POST_BUNDLE_COST||'|'||CFB_COUNTRY_C ODE FROM BILLEDUSAGECHARGES WHERE PARTITION_DATE = SP2-0042: unknown command "SQLSCRIPT" - rest of line ignored.
```

Above string I need to convert as below :
1) After every 80th position there is space character , need to remove that character and replace with nothing.
2) Last part of the string needs to remove "SP2-0042: unknown command "SQLSCRIPT" - rest of line ignored."
so the final string should look like as below :

```
SELECT PARTITION_DATE||'|'||RECORD_ID||'|'||BILLING_ACCOUNT_NUM||'|'||BILLING_ACCOUNT_SYSTEM||'|'||BILL_SERIAL_NUM||'|'||BILL_VERSION_NUM||'|'||SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NUM||'|'||SERVICE_ACCOUNT_SYSTEM||'|'||PRIMARY_ASSET_ID||'|'||ASSET_ID||'|'||CHARGE_CATEGORY||'|'||CHARGE_GROUP||'|'||CHARGE_TYPE||'|'||CHARGE_DATE||'|'||CHARGE_END_DATE||'|'||CHARGE_TIME||'|'||ORIGINATING_NUM||'|'||CHARGECARD_NUM||'|'||DIALLED_NUM||'|'||COUNTRY_CODE||'|'||MOBILE_PROVIDER_CODE||'|'||DURATION||'|'||TM_CALL_QUANTITY||'|'||DATA_UPLOAD||'|'||DATA_DOWNLOAD||'|'||CONTENT_DESCRIPTION||'|'||COST||'|'||COST_BEFORE_DISCOUNT||'|'||DISCOUNT||'|'||ROAMING_IND||'|'||VAT_IN D||'|'||VAT_RATE||'|'||CHARGE_CODE||'|'||SOURCE_SYSTEM||'|'||DESTINATION||'|'||F ILE_KEY||'|'||CREATED_DT||'|'||UPDATED_DT||'|'||CALLING_NUMBER||'|'||EVENT_DIREC TION||'|'||EVENT_TYPE||'|'||EVENT_ROAMING_COUNTRY||'|'||DISCOUNT_INDICATOR||'|'||ACCT_CODE||'|'||AUTH_CODE||'|'||ACCESS_CHARGE||'|'||SERVICE_CHARGE||'|'||IMEI_N UMBER||'|'||EFB_FLAG||'|'||RATING_DISCOUNT_NAME||'|'||SUMM_USAGE_FLAG_BKP||'|'|| SUMM_USAGE_FLAG||'|'||PRE_BUNDLE_COST||'|'||POST_BUNDLE_COST||'|'||CFB_COUNTRY_CODE FROM BILLEDUSAGECHARGES WHERE PARTITION_DATE =
```

Comment: That's two questions. The second is much easier than the first, so I suggest you try to do the second yourself, before you worry about the first.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "Put your long string here" | sed 's/ //3' | cut -d= -f1 | sed 's/$/=/'
```

That should do it.

I found the 80th character is the 3rd occurrance of a space via

```
echo "Your long string" | cut -d' ' -f3 | wc -m
```

Also I suggest you include what you tried before posting along with your question next time.

Comment: I noticed I didn't catch you need to delete the space every 80 characters, my answer will only delete the first space in the 80th position but won't delete the 160th and so on, however you can still use the idea.